# Hiding or disabling passed parameters in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I have a summary SSRS report that I allow the user to drill on. When they click to see details, it take them to a different report and passes the parameters from the first page with it.

My problem is that I have 4 possible parameters, but depending on what count the user clicks on, some parameters have values and some are blank. I do not want the users to have the ability to change the passed parameters. If I mark all of the parameters as 'Hidden' I get an error for the ones without values (The 'day' parameter is missing a value), even though I allow them to be blank or null. I've also tried just passing an empty string or 'Nothing' and I get the same error

Ideally, I'd like them to be hidden, but I'd also be okay with graying them out or disabling them. Passing them in the URL is not an option..

Comment: Do you have default values set?

Comment: That fixed it! Set default value to ="" Thanks